# How to display product image slider's arrow if image count is greater than 4?

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

[image]

I want to display arrow if image count is greater than 4.

In view.xml

```
<var name="navarrows">false</var>
```

I changed from true to false. Now arrow is not displayed but I want arrow if image is greater than 4

Comment: can you please upload your code here?

Comment: @RohanHapani I am not getting proper file where I can modify. I have just gone through gallery.phtml file

Answer (score 3):

Override template file of gallery in your own theme, copy

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

to

> your_theme_root/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Replace in this template (around 80 line):

```
 "navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"); ?>,
```

to

```
"navarrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */  echo (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows") == 'true') && ($block->getGalleryImages()->count() > 4)) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,
```

I hope it will help.